# Dynamic DataTemplate Width

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to design the my application to have dynamic width that is custom to the dimensions of the phone. The code below is the data template i'm using for the listbox i have:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FlightsTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3" Background="#FF171717" Height="35">
                <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="60"  Text="{Binding text1}"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="80"  Text="{Binding text2}"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="150" Text="{Binding text3}"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="90"  Text="{Binding text4}"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="19" Margin="1,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Center" Width="70"  Text="{Binding text5}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

How can i set the width property to be relative to the phone resolution which i know can be retrieved using the following line of code:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` for the ListBox's `ItemContainerStyle`

Like this:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: can this be done to stackpanel, border ... and any item i add to the xaml file??

Comment: StackPanel and Border both defaults to Stretch. It's only necessary to do for the ListBox. The content of your DataTemplate is irrelevant.

Comment: My question is more complicated than this, suppose i have some stack with items being oriented vertical or horizental. So how can i make the height or width of those components relative to the resolution of the phone or stackpanel they are in